# 2-Dimensional Tile-Based Game: Each tile as an object impractical?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, multidimensional-array

I've been trying various ways of creating a two-dimensional tile-based game for a few months now. I have always had each tile be a separate object of a 'Tile' class. The tile objects are stored in a two-dimensional array of objects. This has proven to be extremely impractical,  mostly in terms of performance with many tiles being rendered at once. I have aided in this by only allowing tiles within a certain distance of the player being rendered, but this isn't that great either. I have also had problems with the objects returning a null-pointer exception when I try to edit the tile's values in-game. This has to do with the objects in the 2D array not being properly initialized.

Is there any other, simpler way of doing this? I can't imagine every tile-based game uses this exact way, I must be overlooking something.

EDIT: Perhaps LWJGL just isn't the correct library to use? I am having similar problems with implementing a font system with LWJGL... typing out more than a sentence will bring down the FPS by 100 or even more.

Comment: "bring down the FPS by 100 or even more." You're benchmarking wrong. If you want to know how fast something is, you should look at the time it takes to do something. Not FPS, but milliseconds per frame. 60 FPS is 16.6ms per frame. A 2ms difference could bring your FPS down by 43 frames, if you were running at 166 FPS. But if you were running at 30 FPS, adding 2ms to the frame time only drops you down to 28.5 FPS, not nearly as much. Only the absolute times matter, not the FPS.

Comment: "I must be overlooking something." You may be "overlooking" a lot of things. But since all you told us was that you're making a tile-based game with objects in data structures, we don't have anything to go on. We have no idea how you're rendering them. Your benchmarking snafu means we don't even know that there's an *actual* problem (instead of something you think is a problem but is in reality fine). Give us actual information, and we might be able to help you.

Comment: I wasn't asking specifically what was wrong with my approach, I was asking if the approach itself was on the right track to what is commonly done for tile-based games. To ask what specifically is wrong is to post my hundreds of lines and tell you all to do the work, which is a pretty lazy thing to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For static objects (not going anywhere, staying where they are) 1 tile = 1 object is OK. That's how it was done in Wolf3d. For moving objects you have multiple options.

You can, if you really really want to, store object sub-parts in adjacent cells/tiles when an object isn't contained fully within just one of them and crosses one or more cell/tile boundaries. But that may be not quite handy as you'd need to split your objects into parts on the fly.

A more reasonable approach is to not store moving objects in cells/tiles at all and process them more or less independently of the static objects. But then you will need to have some code to determine object visibility. Actually, in graphics the most basic performance problems come from unnecessary calculations and rendering. Generally, you don't want to even try to render what's invisible. Likewise, if some computations (especially complex ones) can be moved outside of the innermost loops, they should be.

Other than that it's pretty hard to give any specific advice given so little details about what you're doing, how you're doing it and seeing the actual code. You should really try to make your questions specific.

Answer (score 1):

A two-dimensional array of Tile objects should be fine........ this is what most 2D games use and you should certainly be able to get good enough performance out of OpenGL / LWJGL to render this at a good speed (100FPS+).

Things to check:

- Make sure you are clipping to only deisplay the visible set of tiles (According to the screen width and height and the player's position)
- Make sure the code to draw each tile is fast... ideally you should be drawing just one textured square for each tile. In particular, you shouldn't be doing any complex operations on a per-tile basis in your rendering code.
- If you're clever, you can draw multiple tiles in one OpenGL call with VBOs / clever use of texture coordinates etc. But this is probably unnecessary for a tile-based game.